# Epipolar line from epipole and image point

Tags: geometry, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have to determine the epipolar line using this model:

[image]

I read some books and the Wikipedia-article. But I cannot figure out, what this means:

> l2  =  e2  x  x2

Where l2 ist the epipolar line in the right/2nd image (red line) and x2 is the image point in the right image of the object x.

**My problem:** As I assume, the point e2 and x2 are in the right image plane, which means, that the cross product of them (in the formula l2) is perpendicular to the image plane and hence cannot be in the image plane, as the red line is.

What am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write the equation of a straight line in 2D,

```
ax + by + c = 0
```

as a dot product

```
l . x = 0
```

where `l = [a b c]'` is the line and `x = [x y 1]`' is a point on the line.
So, `l` and `x` are orthogonal.

In the second image, both `e2` and `x2` should lie on the epipolar line `l2`, meaning

```
l2 . e2 = 0, l2 . x2 = 0
```

So, `l2` is orthogonal to both `e2` and `x2`. You can find a vector that is orthogonal to both `e2` and `x2` by taking their cross product. Therefore, we can say `l2 = e2 x x2`.

You can see that `l2 . e2`, and `l2 . x2` are indeed `0`, using triple product properties.

```
l2 . e2 = e2 . l2 = e2 . (e2 x x2) = x2 . (e2 x e2) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not look at the points as 2D points in the image that are crossed, that's the source of your confusion.

The cross is defined using 3D vectors such that

```
      |e2x|       |x2x|
l2 =  |e2y|   X   |x2y|
      | 1 |       | 1 |
```

and after you get the resulting l2 (3D vector), you should normalize it so that

```
l2x^2+l2y^2=1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "You should not look at the points as 2D points in the image that are crossed"? What are they if they are not 2D points or 3D points with z=1?